# Orientation Locking to landscape not working on emulator but on device

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation

I have used following code in activity onCreate() to lock view only to landscape mode, it is perfectly working on device but not working on emulator, Since i dont have a device now it's hard to develop

code :

```
  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"

Put this Code[Attribute] in Activity tag of AndroidManifest.xml file it should work.

Comment: its working, i have used "
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);" on my base activity,. Thanx:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, hope this will help you.

Define this attribute "android:screenOrientation="landscape"" as your activity in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file simply add

```
  <activity
            android:name="yourActivity name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if this is too obvious.. You have to manually put your emulator in landscape mode, I think.  I think it's the F9 key, but it's been a while since I've done that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Put below line of code in  your manifest

```
<activity>
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
</activity>
```

It works for me....